# Process Summary suggestions

Tags: c#, asp.net

all.
I am working on some Utility to provide the automated hot fix stuff. I want to show some summary after the completion of the whole process. 
Like how many files i replaced? How many SQL scripts i execute etc.
How can i do this?

I am working on a Windows application.
Can i show an HTML web page with summary? if yes then how?
I have tried it by showing a message box. I don't want to do it this way it's a very long message it's not preferable.

```
MessageBox.Show(LogBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: If you want to show the html content you can use WebBrowser. Or you can  use the users  default borwser and then show the file.

Comment: by directly adding HTML page to my application and showing it by WebBrowser Control?

Comment: You can build  up the html string in your logbuilder and then write it out to the browser as response or you can temprorly write out the html file and then provide link to the user to view  on his default browser.

Comment: How can i do formating then in string builder?. I can not show the whole string at once.

Comment: Any code sample that i can go through?

Comment: I don't know how your logger works. And currently I am on traval so dont have code with me. But you can start building the html as the string with your log message and then use that.

Comment: Ok. Let me try at my end. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I done this by getting my logs in `stringBuilder` and was writing points in HTML `<LI>` element. Then at the end finally write all string to an HTML file and I am opening it at the end.

Thanks all for help.